# Multitouch Gestures on Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: hp, multi-touch

I've recently purchased an HP Envy Touchsmart 15 and so far the touchscreen has worked excellently and I'm very pleased with it. I know of the 4 finger to open the dash and the 3 to move windows so I know the multitouch does work... but it is possible to enable features such as pinch-to-zoom and the like? Things that you'd typically see on a smart phone or tablet?